# How do I resolve this IOException when converting a XML request/response to a String?

Tags: java, apache, jboss-eap-6, jbossws

I receive the following exception when I try to convert a soap message into a string:

```
java.io.IOException: The serializer class 'org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream' does not implement org.xml.sax.ContentHandler.
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:309)
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.EnvelopeImpl.output(EnvelopeImpl.java:320)
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getContentAsStream(SOAPPartImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.getHeaderBytes(MessageImpl.java:1030)
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.saveChanges(MessageImpl.java:1181)
at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1311)
at com.HeaderHandler.handleFault(HeaderHandler.java:155)
at com.HeaderHandler.handleFault(HeaderHandler.java:37)
```

Here is the code that is being executed:

```
SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage(); <-- smc = SOAPMessageContext
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(stream);
```

We just moved to a jboss environment (eap 6.4) and this worked locally in a junit so i'm guessing there is something missing in the environment such as a missing module dependency.

Can anyone shed some light as to what causes this error and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from `java.io.IOException: The serializer class 'org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLStream' does not implement org.xml.sax.ContentHandler.` That is the cause.

How to fix is that you need to use something that implements `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`.

Comment: I apologize and I'll double check the jar when I get back to the office but I thought that this did: https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/xml/sax/class-use/ContentHandler.html#org.apache.xml.serializer